# Dotnet core item template with partial update

Tags: .net-core

I've written some DotNet Core item templates that create a bunch of files as required, but I'd also like to automatically add functions to an existing class (controller, or unit test etc).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want these classes with the functions included in your template every time you start a new project, just open up your template and add them, then export the template.
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not creating a new project, I'm adding files to an existing project (hence the 'item template' in the question).